# Grails Block-level transaction with beforeUpdate interceptor gives StackOverFlowException

Tags: grails

My domain class is like this:

```
Class Account {
    String accountNo
    ...
    def beforeUpdate = {
        new AuditTrial(eventName:"update").save()
    }
}
```

In my application there is a block-level transaction as follows:

```
def updateAccount = {
    Account.withTransaction { status ->
        def source = Account.get(params.from)
        def dest = Account.get(params.to)

        def amount = params.amount.toInteger() 
        if(source.active) { 
            source.balance -= amount 
            if(dest.active) {
                dest.amount += amount
            } else { 
                status.setRollbackOnly() 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

When I try to invoke this `updateAccount` method, it gives a stack overflow exception. It seems to be that the `beforeUpdate` method has been called recursively.

expect your worth suggestions to overcome this problem

Comment: Can you use the code formatter so people can read the code please

Comment: Can you update your question to answer the following: 1) where in your application is `updateAccount` defined? A controller? A domain? 2) Can you post the contents of the exception you receive?

Answer (score 1):

Does AuditTrail have a cascading relationship to Account? That could be causing the problem.

The other thing that could be happening is that saving the AuditTrail is causing a session flush which also saves the modified Account objects.

Have you tried using afterInsert instead?

Comment: afterInsert is probably the better place to do the work. You'll also want to run it in a new Hibernate session: `Account.withNewSession { session -> new AuditTrial(eventName:"update").save() }`